# Error occurred while trying to proxy request /sitecore/shell/-/jssmedia/

Tags: jss

I have an error when running in connected mode (`jss start:connected`)

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /sitecore/shell/-/jssmedia/xlbygg/data/media/img/sc_logo.ashx from localhost:3000 
to http://localhost:3043 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

But when I run with `jss start` it works (my `graphQL` stops working though).

Why is it using proxy for my images in connected mode?

Comment: Do you have SXA installed as well?

Comment: Not that I know of, how do I check that?

Comment: Actually, this error doesn't indicate that. Looks to me like your credentials have not been setup correctly. Did you run `jss setup`?

Comment: Yes, and everything seems to be working but, jss start (graphql not working), jss start:connected (images not working) and going directly on sitecore (dev.xlbygg.no) (graphql not working) all give different results

Comment: @MarkCassidy What does SXA have to do with this?  We have a similar issue running SC10 in docker, and the react app is unable to resolve localhost:3000.  We do have SXA installed, so interested if this is the source of our problems...

Comment: @Jeeby At the time of that comment there were known problems when you installed SXA and JSS in a particular order, it could mess things up (essentially both packages claimed ownership of certain items in the solution). Installing SXA _after_ JSS could cause this. Not sure if this is still the case however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error happens when you run `jss start:connected` and it opens a tab in the same browser that you've used to log into the Sitecore instance. If you open a new incognito browser and go to http://localhost:3000/ then you connected app should open fine, with images, and without errors.